# How to add / view component items to / in a route

Tags: experience-editor, jss

I have some questions about adding items on Sitecore route.

Here is an example :

I created `MyCarrousel` item that display images.

My Sitecore tree :

- Content (directory)

  - MyCarrousel (item)
- Home (route)

  - About us (route)
  - Contact (route)

I added `MyCarrousel` item through Experience Editor to my `Home` route and my `About us` route.

1. Is there an easy way to know which item is in which route ? My example is really simple but for a bigger React App there could be many different items in many different routes and a marketing guy must know where is his content
2. Is it possible to add items on a route whithout going through experience editor ?

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, you can find all usages of a content item in Experience Editor:

[image: EE usage]

2) Yes, but I would not generally recommend using the non-EE method as EE solves a lot of complexity that becomes your problem with manual layout assignment.
[image: layout details]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With the "usage" helper I can tell where one item is used. My question was more : how can I know which component I got on a given route ?

Comment: The component name will show up in the chrome header as you activate it. You can also use the Content Editor's Navigate tab -> Links to see all renderings the current page-level item refers to. It's not super clear or easy to get to but it will show you all the components on the given route.